# PHP: Loading content based on POST / GET user input

Tags: php, post, get

thank you for looking into my question. It's purely related to PHP POST / GET functions.

Here is my code :

index.php

```
<html>
<body>
&nbsp;<p>
<center>
<form action="story_get.php" method="post">
<label for="name">Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name">
<label for="age">Age:</label><input type="number" size=2 name="age"><p>
<label for="place">Place:</label> <input type="text" name="place"><p>

 <label for="storys">Choose a story:</label>
  <select name="story" id="story">
    <option value="sea">Sea side</option>
    <option value="mount">Mountain</option>
  </select>

<p>

<input type="submit" value="Enter">
<button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

story_get.php

```
<html>
<body>


<center>
<h1>Welcome <font color=red><i><?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?></i></font>, age of <font color=red><i><?php echo $_POST["age"]; ?></i></font><br>
to the wonderfull land of <br><font color=red><i><?php echo $_POST["place"]; ?></i></font>
<?php echo $_POST["story"]; ?>



 <p><a href=index.php>Edit</a>
</body>
</html>
```

My code is working fine, but instead of `<?php echo $_POST["story"]; ?>` I want to print 200+ words story relating to what User has chosen. I hope You understand what I'm trying to achieve, and be able to suggest easy solutions. Thanks in advance

Comment: The 200+ words. does it inserted by user in that form, or you get it from a datasource?

Comment: datasource, preexisting story where just name, age and place name will be changed

Comment: Don't use `<font>` and `<center>`, they're obsolete.

Comment: thanks you right here !

Comment: If you can put placeholders in your text, you might be able to make this work with ```sprintf()``` or another member of the sprint family.

Comment: Okay so you want to check if the user has set `$_POST['story']` and if the select is set to an option, you want to display the story ie: `Sea side`or `Mountain`. How are you storing the stories?

Comment: I gues this is where MySQL comes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get that story from somewhere. A couple of ways to get there.

---

If you want to load it from a text file:

```
// Here we sanitize the story ID to avoid getting hacked:
$story_id = preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z0-9_ -]#', '', $_POST['story']);

// Then we load the text file containing the story:

$path = 'stories/' . $story_id . '.txt';
$story_text = is_file($path) ? file_get_contents($path) : 'No such story!';
```

---

If you want to load it from database:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM stories WHERE story_id = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['story']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$story = $result->fetch_assoc();
$story_text = !empty($story['story_text']) ? $story['story_text'] : 'No such story!';
```

This assumes you have a table called `stories` with fields `story_id` and `story_text`.

---

You could also have a separate file with all your stories assigned into variables (assuming you really just have a few, the performance impact of loading unused stories is minimal):

```
$stories['Seaside'] = <<<EOL
Here is the seaside story.
EOL;

$stories['Mountain'] = <<<EOL
Here is the mountain story.
EOL;
```

And then in your story-telling file, you "load" it:

```
$story_text = !empty($stories[$_POST['story']) ? $stories[$_POST['story']] : 'No such story!';
```

---

Then (with any of the above options), simply:

```
<?php echo $story_text; ?>
```

Of the options above, I would choose the text-file loading for sourcing your story text, if you're looking for something simple and easy to maintain. Good luck in telling your stories. :)

---

Assuming you want to use the form variables *inside* your stories. You'll want to use tokens, something like `{{ place }}`, and replace them before you output the story text:

```
$story_text = str_replace('{{ name }}', $_POST['name'], $story_text);
$story_text = str_replace('{{ place }}', $_POST['place'], $story_text);
```

This would turn *"once upon a time there was {{ name }} exploring {{ place }}..."* into *"once upon a time there was Светослав exploring Kamchatka Peninsula..."*, etc.

Comment: great examples, so far I manage to get a story from a text file but also realized that the browser doesn't read the <php> code from the sea.txt, instead of .txt can I use .php ?

Comment: You shouldn't need PHP code in your `sea.txt`. Just store the text there. I've added a note on how to parse tokens into your stories.

Comment: You could also use .php files, in which case you'd use `include 'stories/...` *after* the form submission, and wrap the story into a variable. However, it's cleaner and safer to keep text simply as text. Using tokens, as above, will also keep it portable, should you later want to have your stories stored in MySQL instead.

Comment: Let's say we write the story in Cirilyc like: това and how do we avoid : ����

Comment: By using UTF-8 as the file encoding (everywhere), and having a matching meta charset tag for your HTML, should do it. That's the easiest way.

Comment: when I try to use database option come error Notice:  Undefined variable: localhost in C:\wamp64\www\book\story_get.php on line 18 and line 18 is $conn = new mysqli($localhost, $root, $pass, $stories);

Comment: `$localhost`? Just use `$servername` etc., and define the variable `$servername = "localhost";`.  Same issue with `$stories`. Recommend reading a couple of PHP/MySQL tutorials for a better idea of what you're dealing with. Important: Always use prepared statements when using user input as part of your query.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and explanations! I will learn more PHP and MySQL in order to achieve good results!

Answer (score 0):

`...instead of <?php echo $_POST["story"]; ?> I want to print 200+ words story relating to what User has chosen.`

Use a conditional `if()` or `switch` statement to see if your $_POST['story'] is set and equal to one of your options for story.

```php
//--> ON story_get.php 
//--> (Provided the $_POST variable in fact has the values assigned to the global array)
//--> use var_dump($_POST) on story_get.php to check if the global $_POST array has 
//--> key/value pairs coming from your index.php page

// set variables that have your story information. 
$seaside = //--> Your story about the sea side
$mountain = //--> Your story about the mountain
$output = null; //--> Empty variable to hold display info from conditional
//--> Now to see if the form element that selects story is set using isset
if(isset($_POST['story']){
  //--> Now that we know the input in the form that holds the value for story isset
  //--> Check to see if it is set and then declare a variable and assign it to that variable
  $story = $_POST['story'];
  if($story === 'sea'){
    $output = $seaside;
  }elseif($story === 'mount'){
    $output = $mountain;
  }else{
    $output = //--> Set a default setting that displays output here if neither story is selected.
  }
}
```

Echo the variable `$output` where you wish to display your story content within the html doc

```html
<div>
  <?=$output?>

  <!--// OR //-->

  <?php echo $output; ?>
</div>
```